# Understanding iPhone crash logs

Tags: ios, iphone, crash-log

I'm unable to detect an issue by viewing the below crash log as I'm not an expert in it. 
Symbolication is applied but it seems point 24 below didn't get symbolicated. I don't know why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Incident Identifier: 64AA5ACD-41A0-462C-8169-2689E4C9DFF6
CrashReporter Key:   e3e88a5898a533649d98f91fa4931fa1d7c125f9
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,3
Process:             yanachat [3315]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F46E2E69-F521-4FDF-A1BF-FDEAAFF50C8D/yanachat.app/yanachat
Identifier:          com.soccerManiac.SSChat
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-28 16:57:52.245 +0500
Launch Time:         2015-05-28 16:38:37.031 +0500
OS Version:          iOS 8.2 (12D508)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x25f2c45a __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33e02c86 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreData                        0x25c56b48 _PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 2808
3   CoreData                        0x25c55408 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 144
4   CoreData                        0x25c744c6 _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 82
5   CoreData                        0x25c792ce -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:] + 138
6   yanachat                        0x002116a8 0xe1000 + 1246888
7   yanachat                        0x001e5266 0xe1000 + 1065574
8   UIKit                           0x29479e7a -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 66
9   UIKit                           0x29479e1c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
10  UIKit                           0x29464c3e -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
11  UIKit                           0x29479888 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
12  UIKit                           0x29479562 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 518
13  UIKit                           0x29472e2c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 540
14  UIKit                           0x29449754 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
15  UIKit                           0x296bd2f4 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14164
16  UIKit                           0x294481a4 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1348
17  CoreFoundation                  0x25ef2fba __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
18  CoreFoundation                  0x25ef23ca __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 214
19  CoreFoundation                  0x25ef0a30 __CFRunLoopRun + 768
20  CoreFoundation                  0x25e3e3ac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
21  CoreFoundation                  0x25e3e1be CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
22  GraphicsServices                0x2d46b1fc GSEventRunModal + 132
23  UIKit                           0x294a8438 UIApplicationMain + 1436
24  yanachat                        0x0020b02a 0xe1000 + 1220650
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x3438eaaa tlv_initializer + 2
```

Comment: use dsym file to get address

Comment: From where I'll get dsym file?

Answer (score 1):

This contains essential information for developers who wish to receive and process crash reports for their iOS applications.

1. Report Types

   - Application crash
   - Low memory
   - User force-quit
   - Watchdog timeout
2. Symbolication

   - Symbolication
3. Acquiring Crash Reports
4. The Xcode Organizer

[Understand more detail for cash log with example refer here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs)